# Inline Razor output after dash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I don't know how to output a variable in Razor as part of an attribute name after a dash:

```
<span data-@(DataAttributeName)="value"/>
// fails, output:
<span data-@(DataAttributeName)="value"/>

<span data- @(DataAttributeName)="value"/>
// works, however, the space results in invalid HTML:
<span data- myname="value"/>
```

How to do that properly?

Currently, I have the following workaround:

```
<span @("data-" + DataAttributeName)="value"/>
```

But I don't like it for obvious style reasons + Visual Studio tells me that "an attribute name is expected" and shows an error (although it seems to work properly), also something I don't like.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky part in razor engine, it tries to be smart to save some escape but sometimes leave no easy solution in scenarios like this.

Just to stay neat, I may create a HtmlHelper Extension, which might be a overkill, but just in case you are sick of red things in editor like me :)

```
public static class MyHtmlHelperExtension
{
        public static MvcHtmlString DataAttribute(this HtmlHelper helper, string attrName, string value)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("data-{0}='{1}'", attrName, value));
        }
}
```

Then in your view it can be somehow cleaner:

```
<span @Html.DataAttribute(DataAttributeName, "value") />
```